# How to count a specific element in a collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I know you can count how many elements are in a collection with

```
 collection.find().count().
```

However, I was wondering how can I count a certain element inside the item inside the collection. For example I have four images inside a `Documents` like this:

```
"Documents":{
    "1":"image.png",
    "2":"Test.jpg",
    "3":"Next.png"
  }
```

I was wondering how I can count all the items in Documents? I have tried a few things but none of them are working. Can anyone help?

Example data:

```
{
  "name": "Oran",
  "username": "Oran.Hammes",
  "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brandonflatsoda/128.jpg",
  "email": "xxxxxx@hotmail.com",
  "dob": "1953-03-21T17:40:17.020Z",
  "phone": "364-846-1607",
  "address": {
    "street": "Schultz Stream",
    "suite": "Suite 618",
    "city": "North Muriel mouth",
    "zipcode": "06447-1081",
    "geo": {
      "lat": "57.1844",
      "lng": "-56.8890"
    }
  },
  "website": "misty.net",
  "company": {
    "name": "Hettinger, Reilly and Stracke",
    "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered system-worthy database",
    "bs": "best-of-breed evolve e-markets"
  },
  "Documents": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "image.png",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Test.jpg",
    },
    {
         "id": "3",
         "name": "Next.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

After this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559682/how-to-count-a-specific-elemet-in-a-collection-in-mongodb/34560027?noredirect=1#comment56863187_34559682) I changed my document's structure and it looks like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("568703d08981f193cf343698"),
        "name" : "Oran",
        "username" : "Oran.Hammes",
        "email" : "xxxxxxx@hotmail.com",
        "dob" : "1953-03-21T17:40:17.020Z",
        "phone" : "364-846-1607",
        "company" : {
                "name" : "Hettinger, Reilly and Stracke",
                "catchPhrase" : "Multi-tiered system-worthy database",
                "bs" : "best-of-breed evolve e-markets"
        },
        "Documents" : [
                {
                        "id" : "1",
                        "name" : "image.png"
                },
                {
                        "id" : "2",
                        "name" : "Test.jpg"
                },
                {
                        "id" : "3",
                        "name" : "Next.png"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: *I have tried a few things but none of them are working*. I guess except `mapReduce`  You should change your document structure and make `Documents` an array of sub-documents so you can use the aggregation framework.

Comment: I agree with @user3100115's suggestion to convert Documents to an array. You could then use aggregation and the $sum operator.

Comment: @JamesWahlin `$sum` is not the right operator here because you don't want to **denormalize** the array using `$unwind` the right operator is [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)

Comment: Sorry - yes you are correct. $size is what you want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking it's not a good idea to have dynamic keys in your documents. Your best bet in situation like this is [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)

```js
var map = function() { 
    emit(this._id, Object.keys(this.Documents).length);
};
var reduce = function(key, values) {};
db.collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, { "out": { "inline": 1 } } )
```

Which yields:

```js
{
        "results" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5686e2a98981f193cf343697"),
                        "value" : 3
                }
        ],
        "timeMillis" : 697,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 1,
                "emit" : 1,
                "reduce" : 0,
                "output" : 1
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Definitely the best thing to do is to change your documents structure and make `Documents` an array of sub-documents so that the `Documents` field value looks like this:

```js
"Documents": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "image.png",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Test.jpg",
    },
    {
         "id": "3",
         "name": "Next.png"
    }
]
```

and use the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) your documents and return the number of elements in the "Documents" array using the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) operator

```js
db.collections.aggregate([ 
    { "$project": { "count": { "$size": "$Documents" } } } 
] )
```